# looping a code and ending loop by pressing 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new here and a total beginner of python so please help me. I have done the following to creat a program that tells the user if number entered is Up, Down or the same from the first number entered. my question is, how can I create a loop for it so they user can enter as many numbers then end the process when 0 is entered?

---

```
print ('Please enter your first number')
firstNumber = input()

print('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')
nextNumber=input()

if firstNumber<nextNumber:
    print ('Up')

if firstNumber>nextNumber:
    print ('Down')

if firstNumber==nextNumber:
    print ('Same')
```

---

Thank you

Comment: use a while loop with a break in it

Comment: You need to look into loops, e.g. `while` loop

Comment: What's the problem? You've just described the kind of loop you want to create: the one that reads inputs until the user inputs a zero.

Comment: in python 3, you have to convert your input to integer,else you'll have lexicographical comparison and "10" < "2"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating from english to python, what you want is

```
while nextNumber != 0:
    ...keep looping...
```

So, without changing your code too much, you can simply do:

```
print ('Please enter your first number')
firstNumber = input()

print('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')
nextNumber=input()

while nextNumber != 0:

    if firstNumber<nextNumber:
        print ('Up')

    if firstNumber>nextNumber:
        print ('Down')

    if firstNumber==nextNumber:
        print ('Same')

    # turn the nextNumber into the firstNumber
    firstNumber = nextNumber

    print('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')
    nextNumber=input()
```

There are also a few things you could improve. For example, you dont need to use the `print` statement before the `input`. You can simply do `input('Please enter your first number')`. Also, you could be using `if`-`else` instead of only `if`.

Here is an example of how it would look like:

```
firstNumber = input('Please enter your first number')

nextNumber=input('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')

while nextNumber != 0:

    if firstNumber<nextNumber:
        print ('Up')

    elif firstNumber>nextNumber:
        print ('Down')

    elif firstNumber==nextNumber:
        print ('Same')

    # turn the nextNumber into the firstNumber
    firstNumber = nextNumber

    nextNumber=input('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')
```

---

Now, you say you want to collect all the `Ups` and `Downs` and print them at the end. You can simply create a `list` and append the value to that `list`. Like so:

```
ups_and_downs = []

firstNumber = input('Please enter your first number')

nextNumber=input('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')

while nextNumber != 0:

    if firstNumber<nextNumber:
        ups_and_downs.append('Up')
        print ('Up')

    elif firstNumber>nextNumber:
        ups_and_downs.append('Down')
        print ('Down')

    elif firstNumber==nextNumber:
        ups_and_downs.append('Same')
        print ('Same')

    # turn the nextNumber into the firstNumber
    firstNumber = nextNumber

    nextNumber=input('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')

print(ups_and_downs)
```

Comment: Thank you! can you please tell me how,  after the user enters all the numbers then 0 to finish, the result Up, Up, Down .... is displayed all together at the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
nextNumber = 1 #define 
while nextNumber != 0: #as long as its not 0, run loop
  print ('Please enter your first number')
  firstNumber = int(input()) #python treats input as str so cast to int

  print('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')#cast str to int
  nextNumber= int(input())

  if firstNumber<nextNumber:
      print ('Up')

  if firstNumber>nextNumber:
      print ('Down')

  if firstNumber==nextNumber:
      print ('Same')
```

Output:

```
Please enter your first number
 4
Enter the next number(0 to finish)
 6
Up
Please enter your first number
 7
Enter the next number(0 to finish)
 8
Up
Please enter your first number
 5
Enter the next number(0 to finish)
 4
Down
Please enter your first number
 8
Enter the next number(0 to finish)
 0
Down
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ... may I ask if there is any way to collect those outcomes in the end? i mean after the user enters all the numbers then 0 to end, the result Up, Up, Down .... is displayed all together?

Comment: Yes, use a list to store each input. Look in google on how to use a list.